# How to specify color of multiplot title

Tags: gnuplot

This might be a silly question, but I can't figure out how to specify the  (font-) color for the title in a multiplot.

```
gnuplot> set multiplot layout 2,1 title "Title" font ",14" tc rgb "blue"
                                                           ^
         invalid or duplicate option
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature does not seem to be supported currently "out of the box".

However, it looks like that the reason is just because the color specification is not parsed. To be more specific, the function `multiplot_start` in `src/multiplot.c` parses only font name,size so the remaining tokens in your example cause the `invalid or duplicate option` error.

A bit dirty solution would be to add this feature manually. It seems that to this end, one needs to do the following:

1. add `#include "misc.h"` at line 50 of `src/multiplot.c`
2. at line 255 of the same file, add

-

```
if (equals(c_token,"tc") || almost_equals(c_token,"text$color")) {
    parse_colorspec(&(mp_layout.title.textcolor), TC_VARIABLE);
    continue;
}
```

Then after running the standard `./configure ... && make install` commands, your example produces in this customized version of Gnuplot the desired blue title...

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late acceptance. Been on vacation :)

Comment: The actual fix for this is to submit a feature request upstream and get the feature into the codebase for all users...